# Java How to estimate how much memory method needs, reflectively from JAR file

Tags: java, memory, methods, reflection, jar

I need to estimate how much memory method needs for execution.
I load refletively classes from JAR file and then take specific method from class.
But I don't know how to estimate this.
Is there any way to do this ?

Extra I need estimate how much stack and heap memory method needs for execution.

Comment: You're trying to estimate *in advance* how much memory a method might use? I'm guessing that's close to impossible.

Comment: Yes I would try to do something like estimating in advance or maybe is it way to measure this by executing method ?